# problem with making a string using values of object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm having a problem with creating a new property which contains a string using values of existing properties. could you let me know why I can't get it to work?

```
 function greetDevelopers(list) {
  for(let i=0 ; i< list.length ; i++ ){
  return 'Hi '+list[i].firstName +', what do you like the most about 
 '+list[i].language +'?'
  }
 }
```

when I write a code like this to input new property into each object, it keeps shows the very first object result.

however, if I try it

```
 function greetDevelopers(list) {
  for(let i=0 ; i< list.length ; i++ ){
  return 'Hi '+list[1].firstName +', what do you like the most about 
 '+list[1].language +'?'
  }
 }
```

it shows correct values in the object.

https://www.codewars.com/kata/coding-meetup-number-2-higher-order-functions-series-greet-developers/train/javascript

Your task is to return an array where each object will have a new property 'greeting' with the following string value:

Hi < firstName here >, what do you like the most about < language here >?

```
function greetDevelopers(list) {
 for(let i=0 ; i< list.length ; i++ ){
 return 'Hi '+list[i].firstName +', what do you like the most about 
'+list[i].language +'?'
 }
}

var list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 
'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java' },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 
'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', 
continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby' } 
];
Test.assertDeepEquals(greetDevelopers(list1), answer);

[
  { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 
'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java',
    greeting: 'Hi Sofia, what do you like the most about Java?'
  },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 
'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python',
    greeting: 'Hi Lukas, what do you like the most about Python?'
  },
  { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', 
continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby',
    greeting: 'Hi Madison, what do you like the most about Ruby?'
  } 
];
```

I want to make it like this. but my code doesn't work. can you please help? 
thank you!

Comment: Why do you start a `for` loop, but return within the very first iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to create an array from another array, you can often do it with the `map` function. The `map` function takes every entry of one array and returns a new array. With your case, I would do it like that:

```js
const list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 
'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java',
    //greeting: 'Hi Sofia, what do you like the most about Java?'
  },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 
'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python',
    //greeting: 'Hi Lukas, what do you like the most about Python?'
  },
  { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', 
continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby',
    //greeting: 'Hi Madison, what do you like the most about Ruby?'
  } 
];

const greetDevelopers = list1.map((item) => {
    return `Hi ${item.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${item.language}?`
});

console.log(greetDevelopers);
```

Or, if you really want to add the properties to the existing objects:

```js
let list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 
'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java',
    // greeting: 'Hi Sofia, what do you like the most about Java?'
  },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 
'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python',
    // greeting: 'Hi Lukas, what do you like the most about Python?'
  },
  { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', 
continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby',
    // greeting: 'Hi Madison, what do you like the most about Ruby?'
  } 
];

list1.forEach((item) => {
    item.greeting = `Hi ${item.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${item.language}?`
});

console.log(list1);
```

Comment: I haven't learned map yet but I will study it and try to solve the problem using this one! Thank you!

Comment: Map is generally useful when you want to apply something for each entry in the array. It returns a new array. It is very useful when you want to render your data for example: If you have an array of strings and for each of those strings you want to wrap them in a text component. With map, you do just: const texts = data.map(item=>(<Text>item<Text>)). But I think in your case you don’t want to create a copy of your array but just modify each entry of it. You should use forEach, that iterates through each entry (so you can directly change it), but without returning a new array.

Comment: Thank you so much David. I have studied map, and it is really useful!

Answer (score 0):

You're *returning* the string inside the loop.  Whenever you return, you mean to say you want to stop everything and return the given value, which is fine if, for instance, you were searching a loop for a specific element and then you found it, as it wouldn't make sense to finish the loop.

However, it seems to me what you mean to do is return a string *for each user*.

To do this, you could do the following:

```js
function greetDevelopers(list) {
  let greetings = new Array();
  for(let i=0 ; i< list.length ; i++ ){
    greetings.push('Hi '+list[i].firstName +', what do you like the most about '+list[i].language +'?');
  }
  return greetings;
}

console.log(greetDevelopers([{firstName: 'Jon', language: 'Java'}, {firstName: 'Peter', language: 'English'}]));
```

Alternatively, in more *advanced* browsers, you could also do the following which gives you a more controlled iterator-based approach:

```js
    function* greetDevelopers(list) {
      for(let i=0 ; i< list.length ; i++ ){
        yield 'Hi '+list[i].firstName +', what do you like the most about '+list[i].language +'?';
      }
    }

const greetingsIterator = greetDevelopers([{firstName: 'Jon', language: 'Java'}, {firstName: 'Peter', language: 'English'}]);

console.log(greetingsIterator.next().value);
console.log(greetingsIterator.next().value);
```

More details about yield and the iterator protocol can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice and link!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call you function within the for-loop. You are returning the first result of the list instead of giving it the chance to loop.

```
function greetDevelopers(developer) {
    return 'Hi '+developer.firstName +', what do you like the most about '+developer.language +'?'
 }

for(let i=0 ; i< list.length ; i++ ){
  greetDevelopers(list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `greeting` property to each object in `list` with the string you were constructing.

```js
function greetDevelopers(list) {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].greeting = 'Hi ' + list[i].firstName + ', what do you like the most about ' + list[i].language + ' ? ';
  }
  return list;
}

var list1 = [{firstName:'Sofia',lastName:'I.',country:'Argentina',continent:'Americas',age:35,language:'Java'},{firstName:'Lukas',lastName:'X.',country:'Croatia',continent:'Europe',age:35,language:'Python'},{firstName:'Madison',lastName:'U.',country:'United States',continent:'Americas',age:32,language:'Ruby'}]

console.log(greetDevelopers(list1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for returning an array of object with a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for `firstName` and `language` and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for the wanted string with changing values.

```js
function greetDevelopers(list) {
    return list.map(({ firstName, language }) =>
        ({ geeting: `Hi ${firstName}, what do you like the most about ${language}?` }));
}

var list1 = [{ firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java' }, { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python' }, { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby' }];

console.log(greetDevelopers(list1));
```

Comment: I haven't studied map yet. I guess map can input new property in each object.  I will study more and try this way. it seems a lot easier! thank you so much.